# warning if(ereg error first then other error

Tags: preg-match, ereg

Here is my original code listed below.

```
if(ereg($pattern,strtolower($this->get_domain())) && !ereg("^-|-$",strtolower($this->get_domain())) && !preg_match("/--/",strtolower($this->get_domain()))){
```

This is the error

> Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in

Then I replaced the ereg with `preg_match` below. I receive this error

```
if(preg_match($pattern,strtolower($this->get_domain())) && !preg_match("^-|-$",strtolower($this->get_domain())) && !preg_match("/--/",strtolower($this->get_domain()))){
```

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^'
>   found in

I tried to to put `/` before the `^` and after the `$` but still no luck.  May I get some assistance from someone who might know how to fix this error.

Comment: You just need to put / before the ^ and after the $. If you are still getting same error, Then you may have browser/application cache enabled which may be causing the same error replicated.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj Yes I added / before and after the $ cleared local cache same result.  maybe a application cache problem... hmmm

Comment: What is the content of `$pattern`?

Comment: @M42 $pattern="^[a-z".$idn."0-9\-]{3,}$";
  }else{
   $pattern="^[a-z0-9\-]{3,}$";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add delimiters to your regexes:

```php
$pattern = "/^[a-z".$idn."0-9\-]{3,}$/";// same for "/^[a-z0-9\-]{3,}$/"
//   here __^             and here __^
if(preg_match($pattern, strtolower($this->get_domain())) && 
  !preg_match("/^-|-$/",strtolower($this->get_domain())) && 
  //         __^   __^
  !preg_match("/--/", strtolower($this->get_domain()))){
```